# How do I condense the loop and if else

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Is there a better or shorter way to write this code?

```py
def business_role_code_to_name(x):
    y = []

    for position, code in enumerate(x):
        if position == 0 and code == 1.0: 
            y.append("Owner") 
        elif position == 1 and code == 1.0: 
            y.append("Manager")
        elif position == 2 and code == 1.0:
            y.append("Employee")
        elif position == 3 and code == 1.0:
            y.append("Other")
    return y

assert business_role_code_to_name([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]) == ['Owner', 'Manager', 'Employee']
assert business_role_code_to_name([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]) == ['Manager', 'Other']
```

I am new to programming, I think there is a better way to write this code. Thanks!

Comment: since in every `if` you check that `code==1.0` you can just check it once in the beginning of the `for` loop, it's more efficient

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input list has 4 elements?

Comment: Good question @user202729. I didn't even think about it. In my data, yes, it is guaranteed to have 4 elements.

Comment: Are the numbers meant to be floating point (`1.0`) or really integers (`1`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
def business_role_code_to_name(x):
    y = []
    d = {(0, 1): 'Owner', (1, 1): 'Manager', (2, 1): 'Employee', (3, 1): 'Other'}
    for i in enumerate(x):
        if d.get(i):
            y.append(d[i])
    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

names = ['Owner', 'Manager', 'Employee', 'Other']
positions_0 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
positions_1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

Output:

```
list(compress(names, positions_0))
# ['Owner', 'Manager', 'Employee']
list(compress(names, positions_1))
# ['Manager', 'Other']
```

Comment: If code has anything other than 0 or 1 then it's necessary to check == 1.

Answer (score 1):

The function `business_role_code_to_name` has the same logic as below

```
def business_role_code_to_name(x):
    z = ['Owner', 'Manager', 'Employee' ,'Other']
    y = [z[position]  for position, code in enumerate(x) if code==1.0]
    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `zip` for that task following way:

```
roles = ["Owner","Manager","Employee","Other"]
code1 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
code2 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
def decode_role(rolecode):
    return [role for code,role in zip(rolecode,roles) if code==1.0]
print(decode_role(code1)) # ['Owner', 'Manager', 'Employee']
print(decode_role(code2)) # ['Manager', 'Other']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an example with error handling:

**Function:**

```
def business_role_code_to_name(x):
    y = []
    positions = {0: "Owner", 1: "Manager", 2: "Employee", 3: "Other"}
    for position, code in enumerate(x):
        if code != 1.0:
            continue
        try:
            y.append(positions[position])
        except KeyError as key_err:
            print("{} is a wrong index.".format(position))
            raise key_err
    return y
```

**Test:**

```
print(business_role_code_to_name([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]))
print(business_role_code_to_name([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]))
print(business_role_code_to_name([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
['Owner', 'Manager', 'Employee']
['Manager', 'Other']
4 is a wrong index.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(business_role_code_to_name([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
  File "test.py", line 11, in business_role_code_to_name
    raise key_err
  File "test.py", line 8, in business_role_code_to_name
    y.append(positions[position])
KeyError: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this without foor loops:

```py
roles = ('Owner', 'Manager', 'Employee', 'Other')
def business_role_code_to_name(x):
    positions = filter(lambda k: x[k] == 1.0, range(len(x)))
    return list(map(roles.__getitem__, positions))
```